# How to create a generic function that supports multiple Widget types in Rust / GTK-rs?

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk4, gtk-rs

In nutshell, I wanna create this func (not valid Rust):

```
fn foo<T: IsA<CheckButton> | T: IsA<ToggleButton>>(...) {
    ...
    widget.is_active() // where widget is either a Checkbutton or a ToggleButton GTK4 widget
}
```

But this doesn't work in Rust.

I know I can do this:

```
fn foo<T: IsA<Object> + IsA<Widget>>(...) {
    ...
    widget.is_active() // Compiler complains that this method doesn't exist on Widget..
}
```

However this doesn't work either, because both ToggleButton and CheckButton has its own implementation of `is_active()` and they don't inherit it from Widget.

Is it even possible to make a generic function in such a case?

Btw I'm using GTK4 and GTK4-rs.

Comment: Create a trait with your needed methods, implement it for all types you want to accept, [use macros to avoid boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341177/automatically-implement-a-trait-for-a-type-that-already-satisfies-it).

Comment: OK I see thc. Just want to know if there is an easy way around this, but apparently there isn't. Anyway thx!