Avoiding dependencies when using Rust traits?
Lets say I want to write a function that calculates the ratio of a shape's perimeter and area.
In Python, I would write something like this:
def get_ratio(shape: HasAreaAndPerimeter) -> float:
    return shape.area() / shape.perimeter()

class HasAreaAndPerimiter(Protocol):
    def area(self) -> float: ...
    def perimeter(self) -> float: ...

If I call it with
square_ratio = get_ratio(Square(side_length=1))
circle_ratio = get_ratio(Circle(radius=1))

then a type checker like MyPy can verify that Square and Circle are both have methods that match the signatures in HasAreaAndPerimeter. Importantly, the definitions of Square, Circle, and get_ratio, don't need to know anything about each other.
In Rust, how do I do the equivalent, including the independence?
Things I've tried:

Defining a Trait in the same module as get_ratio. The problem is any Struct I want to use has to be dependent on get_ratio

use ...::get_ratio::HasAreaAndPerimeter;
...
impl HasAreaAndPerimeter for Square {...}


Define the Trait  in Circle. This relies on there even being a trait, which might not be the case for externally defined Structs. Event then, get_ratio needs to know what Structs it might be called with.

use ...::circles::HasAreaAndPerimeter
...
pub fn get_ratio<T: HasAreaAndPerimiter(shape: T) -> f64 {...}


Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341177/automatically-implement-a-trait-for-a-type-that-already-satisfies-it

Rust doesn't have structural subtyping like Python or Go. If you want to be abstract over behavior, you need to go through traits, which are always explicit. I'm not sure what you mean by "Extending the structs before passing them get_ratio, but that can't be done if there's already methods with the required names". You can implement a trait for a type even if that type already has a method with the same name as a trait method.

Don't forget you can answer your own question, not just edit the question with the solution...

This question is similar to: Automatically implement a trait for a type that already satisfies it. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is the way to do it, and Automatically implement a trait for a type that already satisfies it has advice on cutting down the boilerplate
    impl HasAreaAndPerimeter for Circle {
        fn area(&self) -> f64 { self.area() }
        fn perimeter(&self) -> f64 { self.area() }
    }
    ...
    get_ratio(Circle {...})


In my opinion, the most Rust way to solve this, is to decouple get_ratio from the specific trait, and rather condition it on all the general operations you need from the shape, in your case the area() and perimeter() can be implemented as separate traits. This way, when you define shapes, you don't direcly put random methods into their impl, but just implement all the possible traits.
Thus shapes don't know about get_ratio, they only provide some general operations.
get_ratio doesn't care about the shapes, as long as all the necessary operations are implemented
// some module for common traits
mod shape_ops {
    pub trait Area { fn area(&self) -> f64; }
    pub trait Perimeter { fn perimeter(&self) -> f64; }
    
    pub fn get_ratio<T: Area + Perimeter>(shape: T) -> f64 {
        shape.area() / shape.perimeter()
    }
}

// circle.rs
struct Circle{ radius: f64, }
impl shape_ops::Area for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 { self.radius * self.radius * 3.14159 }
}
impl shape_ops::Perimeter for Circle {
    fn perimeter(&self) -> f64 { self.radius * 2.0 * 3.14159 }
}

// square.rs
struct Square{ side_length: f64, }
impl shape_ops::Area for Square {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 { self.side_length * self.side_length }
}
impl shape_ops::Perimeter for Square {
    fn perimeter(&self) -> f64 { self.side_length * 4.0  }
}

// --

fn main() {
    println!("{}", shape_ops::get_ratio(Circle{ radius: 1.0 }));
    println!("{}", shape_ops::get_ratio(Square{ side_length: 1.0 }));
}


This just moves the dependency to shape_ops. If I'm writing get_ratio but Circle is from an external library, then Circle isn't going to know about my Trait to implement it. It could have its own Area trait, but then get_ratio needs to know which shapes (or at least shape libraries) it will get called with, and needs updating to allow calling with Square. They could both use a shared trait, but only if one already exists, which will often not be the case.

@PEJB the trait has to depend on the struct, or the struct the trait. If you control the struct then you can have the struct depend on the trait crate. If you don't own the struct, the trait must depend on the struct. Thems the rules.

Adding to @Alexeys answer, you can also use a separate trait for the ratio with a blanket implementation:
mod shape_ops {
    // ...

    pub trait Ratio {
        fn ratio(&self) -> f64;
    }

    impl<T> Ratio for T
    where
        T: Area + Perimeter,
    {
        fn ratio(&self) -> f64 {
            self.area() / self.perimeter()
        }
    }
}

// ...

fn main() {
    use shape_ops::Ratio;
    println!("{}", Circle { radius: 1.0 }.ratio());
    println!("{}", Square { side_length: 1.0 }.ratio());
}

